# Hand off bot to Skype for business agents - can it support 1:many?

Tags: botframework

I am following this example for agent-handoff: https://ankitbko.github.io/2017/03/human-handover-bot/

The Agent handoff via webchat is working as intended with the perk of being enhanced to let 1 agent talk to multiple customers at a time.

Now I want to know if the Agent role can use Skype for Business instead. **The end goal is to allow 1:many parallel conversations; Agent on Skype for Business able to communicate to multiple customers regardless of Channel.**

I was hoping someone could tell me if that is at all possible before starting (I have no admin rights in Skype for Business, will need permission, they want other things done, etc. etc.)

When I tried out Slack (with a [different example](https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample)) an Agent was only able to talk to 1 customer at a time because there was no way to make the Agent available for anyone else. Because Agent can only connect to MyBot once.

I am afraid that it is the same with Skype for Business where an Agent will only be able to make himself available to the AgentPool by connecting to the Bot (probably sending an explicit message like 'I am available' since there is no back channel). And he can only have 1 Bot connection at a time, thus only 1 customer connection at a time.